# How to add/subtract month to/from date in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, date, timezone

I am getting date by injecting this class in constructor `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime` as:

```
protected $date;
public function __construct(
....
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
....
) {
....
$this->date = $date;
....
}
```

and then, in class this:

```
$date = $this->date->gmtDate();
```

But how can I add or subtract month to this date for Expiration feature ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

`$date = $this->date->gmtDate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+1 month'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
//Our dates
$date1 = "2013-03-01 19:12:45";
$date2 = "2014-03-01 06:37:04";

//Convert them to timestamps.
$date1Timestamp = strtotime($date1);
$date2Timestamp = strtotime($date2);

//Calculate the difference.
$difference = $date2Timestamp - $date1Timestamp;

echo $difference;
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
protected $_date;

public function __construct(
    ..........................................
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date,
    ..........................................
) {
    ..........................................
    $this->_date = $date;
    ..........................................
}
```

> **Difference Between Two Dates**

```
public function getDifference()
{
    /* Check Days after Cart Update */
    $currentDate = date_create($this->_date->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $updateData = date_create($this->_date->date("2021-03-05 06:30:00")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $interval = date_diff($updateData, $currentDate);
    $diffDate = (int) $interval->days;
    echo "Date Difference is :".$diffDate;
    return $diffDate;
}
```

> **Add Minutes, Hours, Day, Week, Month, Year in Date**

```
public function createSendDateTime($whenSendMail, $sendDateTime, $cartDate)
{
    $whenSendMail = "after_minutes"; // value like after_minutes, after_hours, after_day, after_week, after_month. after_year
    $sendDateTime = "2021-03-05 06:30:00";
    $cartDate = "2021-04-05 06:30:00";

    $time = new \DateTime($cartDate);
    $updatedCartDate = '';
    switch ($whenSendMail) {
        case "after_minutes":
            $time->add(new \DateInterval('PT' . $sendDateTime . 'M'));
            $updatedCartDate = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
        case "after_hours":
            $time->add(new \DateInterval('PT' . $sendDateTime . 'H'));
            $updatedCartDate = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
        case "after_day":
            $time->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $sendDateTime . 'D'));
            $updatedCartDate = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
        case "after_week":
            $time->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $sendDateTime . 'W'));
            $updatedCartDate = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
        case "after_month":
            $time->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $sendDateTime . 'M'));
            $updatedCartDate = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
        case "after_year":
            $time->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $sendDateTime . 'Y'));
            $updatedCartDate = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
        default:
            $updatedCartDate = "";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Updated Date ".$updatedCartDate;
    return $updatedCartDate;
}
```